# Explanation in brackets that the translations of the quotes are my own

Tags: traducción

I'm translating a scholarly article (A) that includes citations from another scholarly article (B) written by author X.  B has not been published in Spanish.  Shall I put a note in brackets after the first snippet, as follows?

> "bla bla bla" [tradduciones de las citas de X son mías].

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

The usual phrase to make clear that the translation is your own is:

**[La traducción es mía]**

I prefer square brackets rather than parentheses because the latter are reserved for the text itself, while the brackets show that what they contain does not belong to the text but has some metalinguistic value or cannot be attributed to the author.

Here you can see how often the phrase suggested is used: [Use of the phrase at GB](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22la+traducci%C3%B3n+es+m%C3%ADa%22)

Comment: Also an option (growing in popularity in the past decades, possibly due to influence from English's "translation mine", is *traducción mía*). I generally do parentheses outside of quotation marks, but normally that will be more strongly dictated by a style guide more than anything else (which might prefer it in the bibliography or a footnote)

Comment: @guifa You are right that "traducción mía" (just like "negritas mías", "énfasis mío", "bastardillas mías") is shorter and as clear as the four-word phrase I proposed, in which the article and the copula add nothing.